# Show Character Typed Then Mask With Password Character

Tags: c#

I am looking for a method so that when a user types in a password textbox, the character they typed is displayed and shown for 1 sec. Then it gets masked with the system password character or any defined password character?

I can create an option in the app so that a user can change the textbox, so that it no longer uses a password char but then the entire password is shown :(

I tried using different things using a keypress down event, but couldn't figure out how to do it.

Does anyone have any idea if this can be down at all in C#?

Comment: In what environment? Desktop application, website?

Comment: If it helps, this is how passwords are displayed in Android. It lets you see the character you just typed. The rest are masked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can most definitely be done in C#.

For Windows Forms:

You may want to [wrap this in your own user control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6h7e207%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to keep organized.

An easy way of doing this is, `OnKeyDown`, capturing the character and adding it to your own `private string realPassword`, and appending the character to the textbox for 1 second, erasing it, and appending a `●`. Then simply read your string for the password.

Comment: I have the gut feeling this will be extremely fiddly to get right (consider pasting stuff in, people typing faster than 1 ch/second, etc.), but it's certainly possible.

Comment: Oh yeah, pasting would be troublesome.